# How to find all rows in HBase table that have a specific value in a specific column

Tags: java, filter, hbase, database-scan

In HBase table, I have a column family addr with 3 columns: addr:city, addr:state, addr:zip. I want to find all rows with city = Chicago. any idea which filter to use? What is the java syntax?

Comment: Do you want to find the row only (rowkey), or all data in that row, or particular column in a row that has that particular information?

Comment: i want the entire row

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [single column value filter](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/SingleColumnValueFilter.html) to set whether a row is returned or not based on value in a single column. Example:

```
    Filter filter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("addr"),
            Bytes.toBytes("city"), CompareOp.EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes("Chicago"));
    scan.setFilter(filter);
    ResultScanner rs = table.getScanner(scan);
```